# Using JSON returned via PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

So I'm doing a project for college involving an API for information about food, it returns the food brand, id, energy and fat etc.. via JSON, it also returns lots of other information that I don't want via JSON so I'm wondering how I can be selective with what I return and then use.

I'm connecting to the API using PHP and this is the code I'm using.

```
<?php
//$ingr = "ingr=" . $_GET['foodName'];
$ingr = "ingr=Bread";

//echo getFoodFromAPI($ingr);
getFoodFromAPI($ingr);

//return $decodedData;
function getFoodFromAPI($ingr){
    /*$queryParams = array(
        'Food' => $JsonFood
    );*/
    //echo $JsonFood;
    $api = "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser?";
    $apiId = "&app_id=ABC";
    $apiKey = "&app_key=ABC";
    $url = $api . $ingr . $apiId . $apiKey; //+ $search

    $JsonContents = file_get_contents($url);
    $Json = json_decode($JsonContents);

    //echo $JsonBrand."Hello There Brand";

    for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        $JsonBrand = $Json->hints[$x]->{'food'}->{'brand'} . "<br>"; //used to echo the values of the decoded data
        $JsonLabel = $Json->hints[$x]->{'food'}->{'label'} . "<br>"; //used to echo the values of the decoded data
        echo $JsonBrand;
        echo $JsonLabel;
    } 

    $JsonRec = json_encode($Json);



    //print_r($JsonRec->hints->food);

    return $JsonRec;

};
```

?>

So my question is this, is there a way to return only certain parts of the JSON decode? I don't need/want certain information (eg: Return only the brand & id of the food) and also is there a way I can use the returned data being either a PHP object OR array in javascript (i.e show it to a client on a webpage)

Please feel free to ask me to clarify anything I've failed to explain, like I said I'm a college student so I'm still learning and grasping the languages as I use them.

Also for reference here is the HTML & JavaScript I was working with and again I don't know if this is correct either because there is a mix between AJAX and JQuery.

```js
function find_food(foodName) {
  var vars = "foodName" + foodName;
  var result = "";

  $.ajax({
    url: "sendFood.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: vars,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data + "Data Here !");
      result = data;
    }
  });
  return result;
  //console.log(result);
  //return result;
}

function searchFoodDic() {
  var food = document.getElementById("foodName").value;
  console.log(food);
  //var htmlText = "";
  document.getElementById("searchedFood").innerHTML = "processing...";
  var foodSearched = find_food(food);
  console.log('>>>> searched food: ', foodSearched);
  //htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Train Code: ' + foodSearched[1].brand + '</p>';
  //var filteredFood = getCommonFoods(foodSearched.food);
  //console.log('>>>> filtered food: ', filteredFood);
  htmlText = "Hello";

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //htmlText += '<p class="p-foodName"> Food Name: ' + data.hints[i].food.brand + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-foodLabel1"> Food Label 1: ' + foodSearched.foodId + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-foodLabel2"> Food Label 2: ' + foodSearched.label + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<br/>';
  }

  document.getElementById("searchedFood").innerHTML = htmlText;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="food.css">
<html>

<head>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.html">Administration</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<title> Food Website </title>

<body>
  <script src="searchFood.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div class="food-container">
    <input type="text" id="foodName" name="foodName" placeholder="Enter food eg: Apple, Bread">
    <input type="submit" onclick="searchFoodDic()">
    <div id="searchedFood">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No you can't selectively decode parts of a JSON string (not native-ly anyway, and if there was you'd have more processing to strip out the stuff you didn't want), so just ignore what you don't need. I'm not really sure what the second part is getting at. If you have the data in PHP, of course you can output that data to the page in whatever format you want, JSON being the most used one in my experience when returning data to JavaScript.

Comment: Please keep questions unambiguous and open a second one for a second question 

Comment: Ok that's good information to know thanks Jon, do you know of any guides or anything I can read or watch that show how you use the returned JSON data in JavaScript because using the returned data in the way I want to is the the problem I think I'm facing.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, my suggestion is to read their docs.

Comment: @JonStirling That's not true... there are streaming JSON parsers built for exactly this purpose!  (Of course, this particular situation doesn't require one.)

Comment: @Brad And which part of those are native? It's possible I'm wrong about whether more processing is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array of the data you want to return to the JS. For example, inside your function you could change your code to look like this

```
$Json = json_decode($JsonContents);
$output = [];

for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $hint = [];
    $hint['brand'] = $Json->hints[$x]->{'food'}->{'brand'};
    $hint['label'] = $Json->hints[$x]->{'food'}->{'label'};
    $output[] = $hint;
}

return $output;
```

You can then return this data like so

```
echo json_encode(getFoodFromAPI($ingr));
```

Your JS would look like this:

```
foodSearched.forEach(function(hint) {
    console.log('Brand is ' + hint.brand + ' and label is ' + hint.label);
});
```

You are close to achieving your goal, you just need to return only the 'broken down' data of the API request to the JS HTTP request. At the moment, you are doing the correct PHP logic of breaking down only the data you want to return to the JS, but you are using `$JsonRec = json_encode($Json);` which is sending back **all** of the API request rather than your PHP logic.

Hope this helps.

Here is a working example for you to just test

```
# Eggs
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser?ingr=egg&app_id=47971bbd&app_key=15ddd5fb6a552c59762e2dc7093d5f85'));

$output = [];

for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $hint = [];
    $hint['brand'] = $response->hints[$x]->{'food'}->{'brand'};
    $hint['label'] = $response->hints[$x]->{'food'}->{'label'};
    $output[] = $hint;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
var_dump(json_encode($response)); # Here is what your JS would see
die();
```

Comment: Wow that was really helpful thank Jaquarh, I'm getting an error in my Javascript stating that foodSearched.forEach isn't a function. Should I be using a different function in my case?

Comment: Console.log(foodSearched) and make sure it is an array - I was using jQuery when I answered this so you may jus have to loop through manually using the foodSearched.length

Comment: So I got the forEach function working but it's like all the data from my php is being stored at one index, I have the PHP and JS incrementing correctly from what I can see. Would I need to increment the foodSearched index since that's now an array? I also can't use the . modifier like you do for you forEach loop.

Comment: var_dump() the $output array in PHP and ensure it is correct, I did not test the code - I more jus put it there so you knew what you was doin wrong. $output should be a multi dimensional array lookin like [ [ ‘brand’ => ‘...’, ‘label’ => ‘...’ ] , [ ‘brand’ => ‘...’, ‘label’ => ‘...’ ] ] etc...

Comment: Yeah the PHP seems fine and structured correctly it's when the $output data is brought to the JS then it doesn't keep the indexes etc all the data gets put in the first index of the foodSearched array inside my JS, would I need to do something in my javascript to increment through the array or something like that?

Comment: Can you comment console.log(foodSearched); output for me so I can have a look what you mean, are you using header(‘Content-Type application/json’) and ensuring your only echoing the data nothing else?

Comment: ["Array↵(↵    [brand] => Sogo Bakery, Inc.↵    [labe…Inc","label":"BREAD","category":"Packaged foods"}"]

This is what I see but it's hard to paste here so here's an image of it also. This is what the console displays
https://i.imgur.com/2ro2xtL.png

Comment: How are you outputting the $output variable back to JS? It should just be echo $output; it looks like your exporting it

Comment: echo json_encode(getFoodFromAPI($ingr)); that's the echo at the bottom of my php back to my JS.

Comment: I actually don’t know why it isn’t working for you, do you have header(‘Content-Type: application/json’); before you use json_encode() ? If you do then i have no clue why its behaving like that, maybe another question on SO so we can see the code you have because mine works when I try it on localhost

Comment: Not to worry then Jaquarh your help has been amazing, I'll make another post and see what I can do with that, thanks again.

Comment: So with a little tinkering with the array in my JavaScript I got your solution from above working, thanks Jaquarh!

Comment: No worries pal, feel free to update my answer with your working solution to help future viewers :) ill approve edits